# How to make ui-grid's expandable row take up the full width of the parent grid container even when there are pinned columns?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Firstly, this seems to be working as designed and so I'm having a difficult time tracking down any related github issues. Basically, I want the `expandableRowTemplate` to take up the full width of the parent grid container and not be squeezed by any potential pinned column containers.
[image: expandable row doesn't occupy full width when there are pinned columns]

Has anyone else requested this, or found a workaround?
The closest issues I've found are:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4033
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5942